# How can I wait for two promises within a promise to be resolved before calling a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a forEach on a matches fetch that does this:

```
matches => {
            matches.forEach(match => {
              Promise.all([this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.homeTeam.href)])
                  .then( team => { 
                    match.homeTeam = team[0].teamName;
                  }
                );
              Promise.all([this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.awayTeam.href)])
                  .then( team => { 
                    match.awayTeam = team[0].teamName;
                  }
                );
              this.updateTableInformation(match);
            });
            return matches;
          }
```

**Explanation:** I bring in an array of matches and I go through each match. Each match is a Promise that contains links to the home and away teams.

Those match.home and match.away values are also promises of teams so I wrap the teams in a Promise.all so it is resolved before assigning the value to the string type values: match.homeTeam and match.awayTeam.

**The Problem:**
When I call the function:

```
  this.updateTableInformation(match);
```

It uses match.homeTeam and match.awayTeam but when it gets there, the team promises are not yet resolved, therefore match.homeTeam = undefined;

**The Question**:

How can I wait for the team promises (and the upper level match promise) to be resolved before calling *updateTableInformation(match);* ?

I'm using es6, es2016

Comment: Why are you calling `Promise.all` on an array with a single promise?!

Comment: ^ Yeah, looks like you need to have your `teamService.getTeam()` calls grouped together in the same `Promise.all` array/call.

Comment: @Bergi to be honest with my limited knowledge, I used Promise.all because it is how I know it waits for it to be resolve, and wraping only one element was to ensure the order. I had both teams per match and then team[0], team[1] but sometimes the values were inverted.

Comment: Note the Promise.all doesn't prevent JavaScript from continuing on through the rest of your function. Only the code in the "thens" is waiting.

Comment: Recommend more precision in your language. You can't have "promises within a promise". In fact, there is nothing at all "within a promise", other than some internal state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrap the teams in a Promise.all so it is resolved before assigning the value to the match.

No, for that just chaining `.then(…)` directly to the promise would be enough.

> when it gets to the function `this.updateTableInformation(match)`, the team promises are not yet resolved

*That*'s where you are supposed to use `Promise.all`, to wait for all the promises that you need to wait for and use their results in the `then` callback of the returned promise:

```
function updateMatch(match) {
    const homePromise = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.homeTeam.href).then(team => {
        match.homeTeam = team[0].teamName;
    });
    const awayPromise = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.awayTeam.href).then(team => {
        match.awayTeam = team[0].teamName;
    });
    return Promise.all([homePromise, awayPromise]).then(() => {
        this.updateTableInformation(match);
    });
}
```

Also use `Promise.all` to wait until all the matches in the iterated array are fulfilled. Don't use `.forEach`, use `.map` so that you get back an array of promises to use:

```
matches => Promise.all(matches.map(updateMatch))
```

Comment: Thank you this did the trick! And I learne more than what I ws expecting from this question hehe. Thanks!